# Initial velocity of a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, differential-equations

If a pendulum have an equation of [image]

where k and lambda are constants,

how do I find the initial angular velocity (given that the pendulum starts off from the equilibrium position) such that the pendulum will just reach horizontal?

What I did so far is to find an expression of the angular velocity squared in term of theta.  However, the expression seems pretty complicated and I'm not sure how to progress further...

My expression is [image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: *"What I did so far is to find an expression of the angular velocity squared in term of theta. However, the expression seems pretty complicated and I'm not sure how to progress further..."* Please add that expression to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the first constraints (since when theta=0 angular velocity=w0), you should be able to find the value of C.

Afterwards, plug the value of C back and set the second constraint (theta=pi/2 and velocity=0).  You then should be able to find the expression for w0.